# Sending emails to multiple recipients using foreach and arrays

Tags: php, arrays, email

I was trying to send and email to multiple recipients but it turns out that the message is only sent to the last user that was selected. Can you guys check my codes and tell me I did something wrong?
Here's the code:

```
public function sendFriendsInvitation(Request $request, $account, $group){
    $account = \App\Account::where( 'alias', 'LIKE', $account )->get();
    $group = \App\Group::where( 'alias', 'LIKE', $group )->get();
    $event_group = EventGroup::find( $request->event_group_id);
    $resortName = $group[0]->trip_name;
    $groupName = $group[0]->name;
    $owner = User::find($group[0]->user_id);
    $banner = Extras::getMeta( 'header_email', '\App\GroupMeta', $group[0]->group_id );
    $musers = array();
    foreach ($request->user_id as $user_id) {
        $musers[] = User::find($user_id);
    }

    $arde = \App\Email::where('type', '=', 'uinv')->get();
    $content = "";
    $subject = "";
    if ( $arde->count() > 0 ) {
        $content = $arde[0]->content;
        $subject = str_replace(array('$resort_name', '$event_name'), array($resortName, $groupName),$arde[0]->subject);
    } else {
        $subject = 'Welcome to ' . $resortName . '! | ' . $groupName;
        $content = view('emails.content.content-of-friends-registration');
    }

    foreach($musers as $muser){
        $access_info = '<p>Just follow the link below to register or join. </p>';

        $keywords = [
                     'firstname' => $muser->first_name,
                     'resort_name' => $resortName,
                     'group_name' => $groupName,
                     'access_info' => $access_info
                     ];
        $ar_key = array();
        $ar_val = array();
        foreach ($keywords as $key => $value) {
            $ar_key[] = "$".$key;
            $ar_val[] = $value;
        }
        $contation = str_replace($ar_key, $ar_val, $content);

        $mdata = array(
                       'title' => 'Welcome to ' . $resortName,
                       'event_group_name' => $event_group->name,
                       'firstname' => $muser->first_name,
                       'lastname' => $muser->last_name,
                       'email' => $muser->email,
                       'content' => $contation
                       );

        $m_email = $muser->email;
        $m_fname = $muser->first_name;
        $m_lname = $muser->last_name;
    }
    Mail::send('emails.content.friends-registration', $mdata, function ($message) use ($owner, $m_email, $m_fname, $m_lname, $resortName, $groupName) {

            $message->from($owner->email, $resortName)->to($m_email, $m_fname . ' ' . $m_lname)->subject('Welcome to ' . $resortName . '! | ' . $groupName);

        });
    return response()->json(['response' => true]);
}
```

I can't find anything wrong with it. I hope you guys can help me

Comment: There's a lot of data, variables, etc. that are specific to your case here, but wading through those, the mail message is clearly only sent one time, as it's not inside a `foreach` loop or any other kind of loop. Are you calling the function `sendFriendsInvitation` from inside a loop?

Comment: `Mail::send()` is outside the loop and thus only executed once.

Comment: Thanks guys I appreciate your replies. @PeregrineStudios no, sir. I'll have to loop the `Mail::send` using the `sendFriendsInvitation`